# Plot cumulative values based on column value - matplotlib/python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, seaborn

Goal is to plot cumulative values for each model based on a dataframe with 3 columns:

| date_time | model | cum_value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-12 | A | 10 |
| 2021-01-12 | A | 20 |
| 2021-01-12 | B | 50 |
| 2021-01-12 | B | 70 |

The result should be a line chart with a line for each model A and B (mentioned in legend)
x-axis should be the dates and y-axis the `cum_values`

so far I tried this
`data.plot(kind=line,x='date_time', y='cum_values)`

I got the right axis but the lines are messed up
I thought about splitting up the dataframe for each model but there must be a way to plot without splitting the table

Hope you can help!

Answer (score 1):

You should use [**`seaborn.lineplot`**](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.lineplot.html) and exploit `hue` parameter for `'model'` column:

```
sns.lineplot(data = df, x = 'date_time', y = 'cum_value', hue = 'model')
```

Example of code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np


df = pd.DataFrame({'date_time': np.repeat(pd.date_range(start = '2021-01-01', end = '2021-01-10', freq = 'D'), 2)})
df['model'] = len(df)//2*['A', 'B']
df['cum_value'] = np.random.randint(0, 100, len(df))
df = df.groupby(by = ['model', 'date_time']).sum().groupby(level = 0).cumsum().reset_index()


fig, ax = plt.subplots()

sns.lineplot(ax = ax, data = df, x = 'date_time', y = 'cum_value', hue = 'model')

plt.show()
```

[image]